# CSOM, ExecuteQuery fails on first try

Tags: csom, online

When I execute the following code about a SharePoint online library,
I always get an error when `ExecuteQuery` executes for the first time but it works when `ExecuteQuery` executes for the second time.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string decryptedPass = "mypassword";

    System.Security.SecureString securePass = new System.Security.SecureString();
    foreach (char c in decryptedPass)
    {
        securePass.AppendChar(c);
    }

    ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://mytenant.sharepoint.com");
    SharePointOnlineCredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com", securePass);

    ctx.Credentials = credentials;

    Web topWeb = ctx.Web;
    ctx.Load(topWeb, website => website.Title);
    List styleLibrary = topWeb.GetList("/Style library");
    ctx.Load(styleLibrary, list => list.Title);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    CamlQuery camlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(5000);
    ListItemCollection listItems = styleLibrary.GetItems(camlQuery);

    bool exceptionOccured = false;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            ctx.Load(listItems,
                eachItem => eachItem.Include(
                item => item,
                item => item["ID"],
                item => item["Title"],
                item => item["FileLeafRef"],
                item => item["FileDirRef"],
                item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
            ));    

            // Fails on first try if FileLeafRef is requested
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            exceptionOccured = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptionOccured = true;
        }
    } while (exceptionOccured);
}
```

When it fails, I get the following error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive
>
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

but if I remove `FileLeafRef`, it works from first try.

```
ctx.Load(listItems,
eachItem => eachItem.Include(
item => item,
item => item["ID"],
item => item["Title"],
item => item["FileDirRef"],
item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
));
```

any idea on what is happening here ?

EDIT:

I isolated the code that returns an error so now I provide the full code that can be tested on any environment (you just need to change credentials and URL).

Comment: Where do you declare ``ctx`` ..

Comment: Thanks for your help. I isolated the problem and now provide full code so it can be tested on any environment.